# Burning DVD's to Micro SD card on Win 7:

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, windows-media-player, dvd-burning

I am running Windows 7 with WMP. I have DVD's I want convert to MP4's so I can view them on a mobile device. The mobile device uses Micro SD cards.

I cannot seem to get WMP to burn directly to the Micro SD card - have to burn to a DVD disk (2 required for my content), then copy the files from the DVD disk to the Micro SD card - very time consuming.

How can I shortcut this process and burn directly to the Micro SD card? (which has plenty of capacity)

Comment: Well, you can't "burn" anything to an SD card - all you should need to do is copy the files to it. Why not use one of many free video converters to convert the videos to MP4?

Answer (score 0):

On the heals of Huskekn, go great DVDFab (rip dvd) and [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) (convert to mp4. or appleTV 3 preset). They work great!! Convert to MP4, mount your SD, copy and away you go. I do this a lot for my kidos.